# ASP.NET MVC 4 Core routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have set up the following structure for my website. (see link below)
http://postimg.org/image/ut4klihrp/

- localhost:62540 Goes to the index page of the core
- localhost:62540/www/Home Goes to the index page of the WWW
- localhost:62540/cms/Home Goes to the indec page of the cms

I basically want the 'default' route (localhost:62540) to go to my WWW project. How can i do this or does anybody know a tutorial were the principle for this get explained? Or is this not possible since i use the area method.
Eventually i want to remove the view and controller from the core project.

Route config in www :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "WWW.Controllers" }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the default area in the `defaults`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { area = "www", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new string[] { "WWW.Controllers" }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It still tries to go to the home index from the core project after implementing your code.